# Why is this file failing to download?

Tags: curl

I want to install the latest [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) via the terminal on Ubuntu 14.04. I ran:

```
curl -O https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

But the output was like this and no file gets downloaded:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

I can download other files with curl successfully. And this file downloads if I used wget.

Why is it failing with curl? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket is doing a redirect. By default curl will not follow redirects so you need to use the **-L** flag for this.

```
 curl -L -O https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

By the way, I recommend that you use **-v** when you want to see what happens when curl is doing a request.